# Android - Dynamic text on bitmap

Tags: android, dynamic-text

I'm currently trying to show a score which requires the text to change dynamically in a game.
I've searched around and found that most cases people use XML layout for the text.
My problem is I don't use XML at all for the game because everything are bitmap graphics.
Any tips or suggestion for my situation?

Here is the draw method to draw everything

```
public void render(Canvas canvas){
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Graphics.Coordinate coords;
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(closeBtnBitmap, 700, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(groundBitmap, 0, 315, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(petBitmap, petX, petY, null);
    for(Graphics pics : coins){
        bitmap = pics.getBitmap();
        coords = pics.getCoord();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(scoreBitmap, 300, 20, null);
    canvas.drawText(scoreString, 300, 20, null); //change null to paintObj
}
```

Here is the method to update the score

```
private void updateScore(int score){
    initScore += score;
    totalScore = initScore;
    scoreString = Integer.toString(totalScore);
}
```

It returns NullPointerException at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Native Method). I tried logging the "scoreString" and it shows correctly.

Edit: Solved, NullPointerException caused by null paint object. Simply create paint object `Paint paintObj = new Paint();` and set the object `paintObj.setTextSize(textSize)` and `paintObj.setColor(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: you can use canvas to display text :                                Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawText("your string", 10, 10, p);

Comment: @HirenDabhi Used that solution, but returned error. I've added my code.

Comment: in your code you have pass null in drawText (last parameter) . pass new Paint();

Comment: @HirenDabhi Solved as you said as well. Thanks for the input =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing your drawing directly through a View or SurfaceView object, you may want to check the Canvas documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Specifically the draw text function. This is what I use.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Enjoy!

If you're using an Open GL Surface, I'm not sure what APIs are available. On other platforms I've uploaded my characters as a texture atlas and just placed the textures for the correct text that I wanted on the scene.

Comment: I actually found something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304195/android-displaying-score-as-a-string-on-canvas-is-creating-a-new-string-per-dr
But I couldn't get it to work with error NullPointerException, I followed it perfectly btw. If that's the solution you mean, I'll try working on it.

Comment: Does that setup work for you, or are you looking for a different solution? If it's the latter please explain a bit more about how you are developing your game and I can provide better solutions.

Comment: If you want to post your example code, I can help with debugging it. My guess it is either the canvas object isn't valid or the paint object isn't valid and I can try to help debug it either in this question or another if you link to it.

Comment: You definitely need to create a basic paint object - see my edit to your post and see if that fixes it. The paint object may be null for drawing bitmaps, but not text.

Comment: I've added `myPaint = new Paint();` and `myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);` but still the same error. I've also initialized `scoreString = null;` just in case.

Comment: Did you also set canvas.drawText(scoreString, 300, 20, myPaint)? I think I made edits above but they are gone. Don't initialize scoreString to null, it needs to be a valid string like "100".

Comment: Oh it works! Sorry I accidentally changed your revision. Followed what you wrote there and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6336/discussion-between-nmjohn-and-steven-pongidin)